# Apache Beam: Error syncing pod - executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

#### Setup

I currently have

- A basic apache beam pipeline in python
- An SDK image being build for the pipeline environment.  Using Dockerfile and dependencies managed using poetry.

  - Docker base image is `apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.32.0`
  - Using apache-beam version 2.30.0 in my project and in my SDK container

Deploying via CircleCI using the following:

```py
python3.8 src/ingest/main.py \
  --project=<<parameters.project_id>> \
  --region=<<parameters.region>> \
  --input_subscription=<subscription_name> \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --temp_location=gs://<<parameters.dataflow_bucket>>/temp \
  --template_location=gs://<template_location> \
  --service_account_email=<<parameters.service_account_email>> \
  --sdk_container_image=<sdk_image>
```

#### Problem

The dataflow job is deployed successfully and can be found in the GCP console.  When spinning up a worker, however, I get the following error:

```
"Error syncing pod <id> ("<pod_name>"), skipping: [failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk0"
with RunContainerError: "failed to start container \"<hash>\": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime 
create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: 
exec: \"--logging_endpoint=localhost:12370\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown", failed to 
"StartContainer" for "sdk1" with RunContainerError: "failed to start container \"<hash>\": Error response 
from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: 
exec: \"--logging_endpoint=localhost:12370\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"]"
```

#### Thoughts

We are using this exact same approach in another project which seems to be working fine.

I've seen the

```
executable file not found in $PATH
```

in docker before and want to find out how to view the docker specific logs in GCP to help troubleshoot.

Currently, to view logs, I'm clicking the error message in the Dataflow console, which takes me to an Error Reporting page.
[image]

From there I'm clicking `View Logs` which takes me to the `Logs Explorer`
[image]

#### What I'm looking for

- How to find docker specific (or at least, more detailed) logs, if possible.
- Any insight in to what is going on.

I'm newer to Dataflow so hoping I just missed something simple.  Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view Dataflow Docker specific logs in Google Cloud Console you can do following.

- In the Dataflow job view, click *Worker Logs* and click *View logs in Explorer*
- Click the query text box to edit the query.
- Click *Log name* and select *Docker*