# Apache Beam: error syncing pod: executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python, apache-beam

This is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744435/apache-beam-error-syncing-pod-executable-file-not-found-in-path).  Looking toward a solution now, rather than how to find more detailed logs.  I was able to find logs, but the most relevant seemed to be the `executable file not found in $PATH` error.

#### Setup

I currently have

- A basic apache beam pipeline in python
- An SDK image being build for the pipeline environment.  Using Dockerfile and dependencies managed using poetry.

  - Docker base image is `apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.32.0`
  - Using apache-beam version 2.30.0 in my project and in my SDK container

Deploying via CircleCI using the following:

```py
python3.8 src/ingest/main.py \
  --project=<<parameters.project_id>> \
  --region=<<parameters.region>> \
  --input_subscription=<subscription_name> \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --temp_location=gs://<<parameters.dataflow_bucket>>/temp \
  --template_location=gs://<template_location> \
  --service_account_email=<<parameters.service_account_email>> \
  --sdk_container_image=<sdk_image>
```

#### Problem

The dataflow job is deployed successfully and can be found in the GCP console.  When spinning up a worker, however, I get the following error:

```
"Error syncing pod <id> ("<pod_name>"), skipping: [failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk0"
with RunContainerError: "failed to start container \"<hash>\": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime 
create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: 
exec: \"--logging_endpoint=localhost:12370\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown", failed to 
"StartContainer" for "sdk1" with RunContainerError: "failed to start container \"<hash>\": Error response 
from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: 
exec: \"--logging_endpoint=localhost:12370\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"]"
```

#### Thoughts

We are using this exact same approach in another project which seems to be working fine.

The error is confusing since I'm using a pre-built image as my base image for the SDK (`apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.32.0`) which sets the ENTRYPOINT itself:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/apache/beam/boot"]
```

I thought maybe the above path was missing from the PATH environment variable, so I even tried adding it manually

```
ENV PATH="/opt/apache/beam:$PATH"
```

With no luck

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any external dependencies, because in my case an external dependency conflict was causing the same issue. Resolving the dependency conflicts resolves the issue for me.